# Is there any way to compile C++ code written for Linux under Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Is there any way to compile C++ code written for Linux under Windows?

Comment: That all depends on the code and whether it uses any common libraries or not. Need more input...

Comment: There are lots of ways, depending on what the program does.

Comment: e.g. This will compile on most systems!

#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}

Comment: Do you want a cross-compiler to compile your code on a Windows machine in order to run the program on a Linux box? Or do you want to compile code written for Linux in order to run it on a Windows box?

Comment: @LeeTaylor: actually it shouldn't, `<iostream.h>` is not standard.

Comment: This really isn't possible to give a good answer for with the given information. The code may be generic C code using regular standard library code, in which case it should just compile. Or it could be using a lot of special Linux/Unix mechanisms which are very hard to translate into Windows functionality. I mean, compiling it is one thing - most likely not hard if you use a gcc compiler, making it run properly can be a major task - but it could also be just as easy as making it compile. Depends on the code itself - and since we don't know what that is, your answer will be "Guess so, maybe..."

Comment: You should consider installing Linux (perhaps inside some VM) on your machine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and [GCC, the Gnu Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org).

- http://www.cygwin.com
- http://gcc.gnu.org

Comment: I don't know what that `hxxp` stuff was about but I fixed it.  URLs should be clickable.

Comment: Alright, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CygWin, which provides a POSIX compatibility layer and a GNU Linux-compatible toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you can use Cygwin which includes the gcc and g++ C and C++ compilers. You should also be aware that you can use Eclipse as your IDE with Cygwin. Just be sure to install the Eclipse CDT plugins and make sure that the Cygwin binary directories are in your PATH environment variable before you configure CDT. If you already use Eclipse on Linux for your C++ development this should be a fairly painless transition.